# Powershell Only:File name change according to mapping file and then copy to another directory

Tags: powershell

I have a mapping file in import.CSV as following:

```
Name|Business
Jack|Carpenter
Rose|Secretary
William|Clerk
```

Now, I have a directory which contains files like

```
90986883@Jack@Sal@1000.dat
76889992@Rose@Sal@2900.dat
67899279@William@Sal@1900.dat
12793298@Harry@Sal@2500.dat
```

Please note @Sal will always be there after Name. I need to pick these files and put into another directory and end result in second directory should look like.

```
90986883@Carpenter@Sal@1000.dat
76889992@Secretary@Sal@2900.dat
67899279@Clerk@Sal@1900.dat
```

Basically Files need to be renamed based upon CSV file and if Name is not there in file name , then there is no action required. Please note that source file should not be changed.

I will appreciate all kind of help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to extract the string between @ and @Sal and replace with a static string but i am not able to do it on the fly after reading the import file.

Comment: Show us some of your code. This site is for helping others to improve their code not to create the complete code for others. Always add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. Just edit your question. Code in comments is to hard to read.

Comment: Why would file `76889992@Rose@Sal@2900.dat` remain unchanged and not renamed as `76889992@Secretary@Sal@2900.dat` ?

Comment: Theo, my bad, I have made the corrections. It should change indeed.

Comment: This is what ,I have been able to do so far......   $SourceP="E:\Source"
$TargetP="E:\Target"

Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $SourceP\*STATICTEXT1*.dat -Destination $TargetP
ls $TargetP\*.dat | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '(?<=@).*?(?=@Sal)','STATICTEXT2'}   This does the replace Static text1 with static Text 2 and also copy the file to other directory, I want help in fetching the texts from import.csv file.